# How to change item color in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How can I change the item color when being clicked in Javascript? Not allowed to change in HTML nor CSS.

Tried this but not working:

```
$("#image1").click(
        function(){
            $(this).css({color:'white'});
        },
        function(){
            $(this).css({color:'black'});
        }
    );
```

However, it does work when I tried the alert function:

```
$("#image1").click(
        function(){
            alert("Hello");
        }
    );
```

HTML (item is a dot created in css, 20px):

```
<div id="funded_courses">
            <span id="image1" class="dot"></span>
            <span id="image2" class="dot"></span>
            <span id="image3" class="dot"></span>
            <span id="image4" class="dot"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Paste the HTML as well.

Comment: color of image ????  text color ?

Comment: I don't see ant text in the span. `color` property is used for text color.

Comment: It's a dot (20px in radius) created using CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#image1").click(function(){
    var default_color = "black";
    $(".dot").each(function( index ) {
        $(this).css("color": default_color);
    });
    $(this).css("color":"white");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try applying background-color instead of color as this is an image.

Comment: but it wouldn't work if i were to change to click function instead of hover :/